# Detect pending changes through reusable code in all edit pages in angular to alert user

Tags: angular, angular15

As part of one of the requirements, I need to find if user have pending changes and if he hit back button or hit refresh then need to alert. We are using canDeactivate angular guard to prevent on the single page but we need to do it across all the pages. Hence we are looking for reusable code for all pages. we are exploring it achieving via directive. Any suggestion here much appreciated. Below is our current code for single page check.

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
 canDeactivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> 
  {
  return (
  (!this.NameFormControl.dirty)
  }
```

Comment: why do you use a HostListenenr, a guard should be used in the routing module...

Comment: @Random agree. I am just doing R&D  We have been using in routing . Any suggestion on how I can make resuable code in directive or other way to detect changes?

Comment: Actually, all you have to do is to make a class with this method, and any component may extend it.